# Can I use ng-include to include one div in another?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular.js we have `ng-include` directive. We can use it to include HTML inside DIV element.

```
<div ng-include src="foo/bar.html"></div>
```

Right now I develop an edit form where I want to change its look depending on some "mode" flag. In particular I want to hide some form group and move another to different column. I can do it using ng-show and ng-hide flags but I have redundant code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group" ng-hide='mode == "Edit"'>...</div>
   <div class="form-group">...</div>
   <div class="form-group">...</div>
   <div class="form-group" ng-show='mode == "Edit"'>Redundancy</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group" ng-hide='mode == "Edit"'>Redundancy</div>
   <div class="form-group">...</div>
   <div class="form-group">...</div>
</div>
```

Can I use ng-include (or some other Angular feature) to extract `Redundancy` to some div and include it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,

You can do. But why you don't use a controller ? You can create an object to manage this.

Example:

You can create an object which contains template url when init the view will check  based in conditional then show inside ng-include.

Comment: Hi Leonan, could you please provide some code sample? I'm not sure what do you mean.